# Best method to upload images using website1 to save in website2?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, file-upload, web

What is the best method in .NET to upload images using website1 but after re-sizing and renaming the image, saving it to a folder within different website2 ??

Both websites are hosted on the same windows 2008 server.

I want to store all of the resized images in one location, so that a few websites can read the image address from a centralized Sql database and display appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options. Here are two.

1. Map a virtual path within IIS on each website to the same physical folder on the server.
2. Save the file to a location on the server and create a handler (or MVC Action) which reads the files from that folder.  Create the handler/action with a configurable file path that can be set to indicate that folder relative to the currently running app.

Comment: The virtual path mapping sounds smooth enough.
Would passing the file to a webservice on the website2 be a way of achieving this too? or would there be problems associated with that option?